# How do I plot a cycloid parametrically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, parametric-equations

I'm in a beginning python class and I'm supposed to plot this [*cycloid*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid) using subplots. I was given the cycloid in parametric form and told to leave it in that form.

Here are the equations I was given:

```
x = r (θ − sin θ )

y = r (1 − cos θ )
```

`r` is supposed to be a user input into my function.

I don't understand how to define theta, or [*how to plot parametrically*](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus_online/section10.04.html). thank you so much!!

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sympy as sp

def cycloid(r):
    x = r(theta - sp.sin(theta))
    y = r(1 - sp.cos(theta))
    sp.plot_parametric(x, y, (r, -2*sp.pi, 2*sp.pi))
    plt.show()

cycloid(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# Various imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt, cos, sin
import numpy as np

def cycloid(r):
  x = [] #create the list of x coordinates
  y = [] #create the list of y coordinats
  for theta in np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100): #loop over a list of theta, which ranges from -2π to 2π
    x.append(r*(theta - sin(theta))) #add the corresponding expression of x to the x list
    y.append(r*(1 - cos(theta))) #same for y
  plt.plot(x,y)  #plot using matplotlib.piplot
  plt.show()  #show the plot

cycloid(5) #call the function
```

You can change the resolution of the plot by changing the "100" in the `np.linspace` parameters. Try to set it to very low (5) then very high (1000) to see the difference.

Comment: No problem, please validate/upvote my answer if it works for you, to mark this question as solved.